# Should I implement IDisposable for a User Control?

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a .NET User Control. Do I need to implement the `IDisposable` interface for my User Control?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Control` already implements `IDisposable`

You only need to *override* the implementation if you need to dispose some unmanaged resources.

So the simple answer: **no, probably not**.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, Control already implements IDisposable. The base implementation is usually generated in the .Designer.cs file if you did any sort of auto-generation of the Control using Visual Studio. You just need to add to the base implementation if you need to.

It has a [virtual Dispose method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4zkb31d.aspx) which takes a boolean flag. If True, then Dispose was called via the interface. If False, then Dispose was called via the finalizer.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you have external resources that need to be released quickly.  Otherwise, those resources may be held on to for as long as the object remains uncollected, and possibly longer than that.